# Docker mysql container Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts

Tags: mysql, .net, docker, docker-compose

I'm working on a `asp .net core 5.0 web application` which i'am running on docker using docker-compose. I have 2 services my `asp.net core` application and `MySQL`
when i try to run the EF command `add-migration` i get this error :

```
 Unable to connect to any of the specified MySQL hosts.
```

This is the code for my `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/aspnet:5.0 AS base
EXPOSE 8008
WORKDIR /app
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/sdk:5.0 AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["chatroom.csproj", "."]
RUN dotnet restore "./chatroom.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/."
RUN dotnet build "chatroom.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "chatroom.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 5000
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "chatroom.dll"]
```

And this is the code for my `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.0'
services:
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    container_name: mysqldb
    environment:
      MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root      
      MYSQL_DATABASE: livredb
      MYSQL_USER: wassef
      MYSQL_PASSWORD: hw
    restart: always
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"

  web:
    image: chatroom
    build: 
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    ports:
      - "8008:5000"
    depends_on:
      - db
```

And this is my `ConnectionString`

```
"ConnectionStrings": {
    "mydb": "server=db;port=3306;userid=wassef;password=hw;database=livredb;"
  },
```

by the way i can see my database being created when i access my `MySQL` client

Comment: who creates your database? In your docker-compose I dont see the classic entrypoint.db in your mysql compose. Is your error the inexistence of the database insdide your mysql container or the mysql connection error in your netcore app?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out that The host network cannot access the docker network. The docker network is for container-to-container communication only. Therefore i changed my ConnectionString server to `server=localhost`